# equivariant with respect to $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})=SO^+(2,1)$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, differential-forms

I have a trouble with the following:

Consider $\mathbb{H}=\{x^2+y^2-z^2=-1, z>0\}$. Let $g^\mathbb{H}=dx \otimes dx +dy\otimes dy - dz\otimes dz$. Let
$$\psi: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}^{+}: (x,y,z) \mapsto \frac{i-y}{z-x}.$$

Show that $\psi$ is equivariant with respect to  $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})=SO^+(2,1)$

I guess it's related to the commutative diagrams but don't have an idea about how to prove the commutativity.

Comment: Compute partial derivatives of $\psi$ so that you can pull back $dw_1$ and $dw_2$. Am referring to the coordinates of $H^+$ as $w_1$ and $w_2$ (written as $w_1 + i*w_2$).

Comment: You should also define $\mathbb H^+$ and $g^{\mathbb H^+}$ even though some of us know what they are. Do you know how to compute pullbacks?